# Center absolute div inside relative parent with dynamic width

Tags: html, css, css-position, absolute

I need to center(left to right) absolute elements(green) inside a relative container(blue). The child elements(green) need to have a dynamic/unset width. I would rather not use JavaScript(CSS and html only).

[image]

Code:

```css
.relativeParent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.absoluteChild {
  display: block;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
  <div class='relativeParent'>
    <div class='absoluteChild'>test</div>
  </div>
  <div class='relativeParent'>
    <div class='absoluteChild'>asd asdf asdf asdf asdfa sdf</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My solution for this was this ```transform: translate(calc(-50% + 50px) , 0);```. This only works because I assume the with of the parent will be 100px and not change.

Answer (score 1):

Add `left: 50%;top: 50%;transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` to absolute div.

```css
.relativeParent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.absoluteChild {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.flexParent {
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 12px 0;
}

.flexParent .child {
  background: blue;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
  <div class='relativeParent'>
    <div class='absoluteChild'>test</div>
  </div>
  <div class='relativeParent'>
    <div class='absoluteChild'>asd asdf asdf asdf asdfa sdf</div>
  </div>
  <div class='flexParent'>
    <div class='child'>asd asdf asdf asdf asdfa sdf asd asdf asdf asdf asdfa sdfasd asdf asdf asdf asdfa sdfasd asdf asdf asdf asdfa sdfasd asdf asdf asdf asdfa sdf</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The only problem is the green cannot fill the width of the blue container. This is probably why you increased the width of the blue box to 200px.

Comment: I have modified the code. Please check. If you think the content of child div can be more parent, then you will have to set parent div using javascript. In that case, the best option will be to `display: flex;`, I have added the sample code in answer

Comment: Now "test" does not have dynamic width. I think you see the issue. This ended up working for me.     transform: translate(calc(-50% + 50px) , 0);